# Do USB Mixers and USB Audio Interfaces Provide New "Outputs" in Windows?

Tags: audio-interfaces, usb, windows

I've been podcasting with a really simple mixer for some time now. I've recently gotten into streaming and live podcast recording. I've reached the point where I would like to have a lot more control over where my various audio sources go.

I would REALLY like a mixer where I can send multiple audio sources in the same PC to separate channels on the mixer so I can the send them where I would like.

An example... imaging I have a PC game, a soundboard, and a Skype conversation all going on in the PC. I'd like to have the PC Game go to line 1, the Soindboard to line 2, and the Skype to line 3 so that I can then send them to various separate recorders, PCs, etc...

Is the typical function that a USB Mixer would provide? If some fo and some don't,  then how would I know? As an example, I was looking at [this mixer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073YGJ5KB), but I can't tell if it provides the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: This device appears to be a multi-output device, so yes. You should be able to do what you are seeking. You just have to ensure that you can configure your software to utilise the correct outputs from the USB mixer.